# javascript animated table update contents

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql

I have a javascript animated table I want this to get the content from another page and update when a new record is added to the database.

javascript:

```
var newitem = function(){
var item = $('<div>')
    .addClass('item')
    .css('display','none')
    .text('content.php')  -- Get the content somehow?
    .prependTo('#scroller')
    .slideDown();
$('#scroller .item:last').animate({height:'0px'},function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
}

setInterval(newitem, 2000);
```

content.php:

```
include ('db.php');
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `feed` ORDER BY `timez` DESC";
$res2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
while($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)){

$user = $row3['username1'];
$action = $row3['action'];
$user2 = $row3['username2'];

echo ''.$user.''.$action.''.$user2.'';
```

Example (http://jsfiddle.net/8ND53/) How can I make this work with my php and make the javascript only animate and update when new content is added to the database?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **Ajax** for that

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'your data point in php',
    data : {data you want to send},
    dataType : 'application/json',
    success: function(response) {
        // Only when successful animate the content
        newItem(response);
    } 
});

var newitem = function(response){
    var item = $('<div>')
        .addClass('item')
        .css('display','none')
        .text(response)
        .prependTo('#scroller')
        .slideDown();
    $('#scroller .item:last').animate({height:'0px'},function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how my content.php should be set up and what needs to go into "data : {data you want to send},". I can't get this to work.